# calling daxpy from C. What is going wrong?

Tags: c, blas

I am trying to use some BLAS routines in my C code just to experiment and something is going wrong for some reason that I do not understand. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 100000
void daxpy_(int* n, double* alpha,
            double* x, int *incx,
            double* y, int *incy);

int main(){
    static double x[N], y[N];
    double a = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        x[i] = 1;
        y[i] = 1;
    }
    int n = N;
    int incx = 1;
    int incy = 1;
    daxpy_(&n, &a, x, &incx, y, &incy);
    for (i = 0;i < 10;i++){
        printf ("%d  ",x[i]);
    }
}
```

To check whether the answer is correct I print the first few entries of y. I realize that I set a = 0 so the y vector should be unchanged as the result should be ax + y. See http://www.mathkeisan.com/usersguide/man/daxpy.html . However the result gives me all zeroes. Also when I change a to different I get completely random looking results, for instance setting a = 0.2 I get that the output is a vector containing only 858993459. I am probably missing something really trivial. I am compiling using Cygwin and typing

```
 gcc -o daxpy daxpy.c -lblas
```

which I think should be fine. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: I have set N to 5 and here is the output when I run it

```
0  0  0  0  0
```

Also, when I change a = 0.2 the output gives

```
858993459  858993459  858993459  858993459  858993459
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip but it does not seem to work. When I do this I actually get no output at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, one of them is undefined behavior, the other one probably just a minor oversight in reading the documentation:

```
for (i = 0;i < 10;i++){
        printf ("%d  ",x[i]);
    }
```

You use the format specifier `%d` for a double value. Use `%f` instead.

```
for (i = 0;i < 10;i++){
        printf ("%f  ",x[i]);
    //            ^
    }
```

Also, according to documentation, the output will be stored in `y` rather than `x`.

Comment: Useful to catch that format string error, warning flags. for GCC, try -Wall. It will complain when you use the wrong format string for an argument.

Comment: @PegasusEpsilon Compiling without any warnings shouldn't be done, I agree. I personally usually use (at least) `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -Wfatal-errors`.

Comment: @stefan TIL -Wshadow. I use -Wall -Werror -pedantic and call it a day, but -pedantic is something I can certainly see leaving out since it messes with various libdl calls. Either you have to wrap them in #pragma, or leave -pedantic out. I go for the former. libdl isn't portable anyway.